# Change color of top bar and hamburger menu

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp-xaml, template10

I'm using Template 10, and where can I change the color of the top bar and the hamburger menu?
I would like to change the color but I did not find any option to do this

Comment: Yes, I want to change the PageHeader color and panel color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Styles folder Custom.xaml perhaps.
These three:`
CustomColor, ContrastColor, SystemAccentColor.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.